# How to render direction arrows over a vector layer in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I am approaching to find a good solution to render the idea of a migratory direction over a vector layer in OpenLayers 6.

My vector layer is a geojson file including a series of polygons that represent migratory areas in the oceans. Each area has a number of attributes (= features) that are needed to show/hide specific areas via a filter.

I want to add a visual idea of the main migratory directions to each area, such as north-south, east-southeast.

I saw the example reported in the OL documentation ([marker animation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html)), but I should create as many polylines as the number of areas. I don't know if this is the best solution.
Alternatively I was considering the idea of creating geo-referenced symbols in qGIS that I can upload to OpenLayers, which seems rather easier.

Are there other solutions that I didn't consider?

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? Something like this (click on map to see arrows): http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.flowarrow.html?

Comment: Thank you @TomazicM this solution seems pretty interesting. I am going to explore it. Yesterday I tried the qGIS way which also seems feasible, as migration direction  will not come from specific coordinates, but it will be a graphic representation based on the scientific knowledge, as today, for each specific area.